# Imported objects available within model but not within model's method

Tags: python, django, django-models

Within my models file, models can access imported items from within the model itself (as expected), but not from within the model's methods.  For example:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

foo1 = datetime.now() # this assigns successfully

class ServiceEventManager(models.Manager):
    foo2 = datetime.now() # this assigns successfully

    def getCurrentEvents(self, state_type=None):
        foo3 = datetime.now() # this fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'now'

        from datetime import datetime as datetime2
        foo4 = datetime2.now() # this assigns successfully
    ....
```

The problem also affects models inheriting from models.Model (the one above is models.Manager), and besides the imported items (e.g. datetime), model methods give the "NoneType" error when they refer to other models or functions local to the models file.

This problem is somewhat bizarre since (a) it only affects the models file (in the forms file, I'm able to refer to imported functions within Class methods), and (b) it only affects web sessions (when I test out the models from the command line, there's no problem.)

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look for something in your code/model that is doing 'datetime = None' or 'datetime = something_that_returns_None()'

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't think this is the issue here since it affects all imported functions called from within any method in any model, not just datetime.